# Using Annyang on Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, annyang

I'm trying to use Annyang ( https://www.talater.com/annyang/ ) on my Android app.
Annyang works very well on my PC Chrome browser, even my mobile Chrome browser.
However, when I use Annyang on Android WebView, it shows an error to me -

> "I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(18)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'addCallback' of null", source:
>   http://192.168.43.105/Annyang/annyang.html (18)"

I was wondering why Android WebView cannot read property 'addCallback', even my Annyang works well on my browser.
Please help me use Annyang on Android WebView!

The following is my code... 
**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="kr.kro.richvillage.annyangtest">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package kr.kro.richvillage.annyangtest;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mainPage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainPage = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.main_page);
        mainPage.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mainPage.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        mainPage.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mainPage.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.105/Annyang/annyang.html");
    }
}
```

**annyang.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Annyang API Test</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="annyang.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            annyang.addCallback('result', function(phrases) {
              console.log('Speech recognized. Possible sentences said:');
              console.log(phrases);
              console.log(phrases[0]);
            });
            annyang.setLanguage("ko");
            annyang.addCommands(commands);
            annyang.start();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for my bad English, thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Did you solve the problem ?

Comment: Not yet, I wonder why this is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run into the same problem, seems like the Android WebView does not support the speech recognition API.

Here is the Chromium Bug Ticket from 2015:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=487255